# Getting whole object from Odoo relation via API

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

There are lots of Odoo models having relations. E.g. the `res.partner` model has a `one2many` relation called `bank_ids` where I can get bank account information for a customer. When I want to have them I need to get the customer (e.g. by ID) from the API and I have to get the `res.partner.bank` models depending on the values returned in the `bank_ids` field of the `res.partner` object with a second API call.

This is what I would like to prevent, a second API call. Is it possible to change the `res.partner` model so that I get the `res.partner.bank` objects instead of the IDs?

Comment: Do you mean access via XML API or directly via Python ORM API?

Comment: I mean access via XML-RPC API.

Answer (score 0):

That's the standard recordset behavior. See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html

Assuming you have a record called `partner`, you can access its banks with

```
for bank in partner.bank_ids:
    # do your stuff with 'bank', like calling bank.name
```

where bank is a record of model `res.partner.bank`

Comment: `bank_ids` only contains the ID of the bank (account) not the bank itself, or isn't it? So how does your for loop work? Within the loop you have to get the bank from Odoo by ID. Or do I get this wrong?

Comment: Improved comment. bank is a record of model res.partner.bank, so you can access its data with bank.name for instance

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that your answer is possible with Python. Now I understand it, but my access is via XML-RPC.